# Destroying an AngularJS $interval which is started in an ngDialog modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-dialog

I have a modal showing a data table. The underlying data is updated every few seconds using an $http and $interval, but only when the modal is showing. I am using the [ngDialog](https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog) library for the modals. I need the update to stop on modal close, but I don't know the best way to trigger this destruction. Some code:

```
$scope.openModal = function() {

var refreshModal = function() {
   $http({
       params: {proj_id: $scope.projectId},
       url: '/projects/_get_data',
       method: 'GET'
   })
   .success(function(data, status, headers) {
       $scope.modalData = data.data;
       $scope.updateModal()           
   })
   .error(function(data, status, headers) {
       console.log('it didnt work');
   }); 
}

refreshModal();

$interval( function() { refreshModal(); }, refreshRate);

ngDialog.open({ template: 'ModalId', scope: $scope, className: 'table-modal', showClose: false });

};
```

How can I detect the modal closing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing would be to pass the instance of your $interval into the modal close event, and upon closing the modal, to kill it.

Something like:

```
var interval = $interval( function() {refreshModal(); }, refreshRate);
var dialog = ngDialog.open(...);
$rootScope.$on('ngDialog.closed', function (e, $dialog) {
     //identify if the dialog instance closing is the one the interval is for
     if ( areTheSame(dialog, $dialog) ){
          $interval.cancel(interval);
     }  
 });
```

**Edit: for @zbycz** 
Another, cleaner solution would be to use the fact that the dialog has a [closePromise](https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog#closepromise-promise):

```
var interval = $interval( function() {refreshModal(); }, refreshRate);
var dialog = ngDialog.open(...);
dialog.closePromise.then(function(){
    $interval.cancel(interval);
});
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks very much, I didn't know you could relate a close event to the modal like that.

Comment: This isnt a clean solution. The event reacts to any closed dialog, so if you put one more dialog on top, the close events would fire as well.

Comment: @zbycz you are right, there should be code that checks whether the newly closed dialog is the one we cared about.